# Rebase Git commit history

Tags: git, git-rebase

My current git history looks like this:

```
develop:  A -- B -- C
                     \
feature1:             D -- E
                            \
feature2:                    G -- H -- I
```

But, I would prefer this, instead:

```
feature2:             G' -- H' -- I'
                     /
develop:  A -- B -- C
                     \
feature1:             D -- E
```

Can someone help me with such a rebase, as well as explain the rebase command used for me, if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Read the manual, and found this:

```
git rebase --onto develop feature1 feature2
```

Comment: As a strategy, I normally try to build *every* new feature as a fork of master (or develop in your case). It gives me the flexibility to merge and release features in any order, in any combination, and rebase them onto each other as necessary without necessarily affecting any of the others.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer exactly the same. Just that in this case, I branched off another feature accidentally. Hence, I was trying to rebase it so that it seems to be a branch of `develop`.